# getting the right variables in a foreach loop (flex - googlemaps)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, logic

I'm trying to get specific variables out of a for each loop. These variables are used to display a click event on a marker on a map. If you click the marker on the map, the details pop over it. Now these details are being overwritten each time the loop starts (50 times). The solution I'm looking for, let's me select a marker on the map with the according detail attached to it.

There might be an easy solution but I haven't found it yet.

The code :

```
for each(artistXML in artistList.events.event)
                {
                    var gLat:int =  artistXML.venue.location.*::point.*::lat;
                    var gLong:int = artistXML.venue.location.*::point.*::long;

                    var evntLng:LatLng = new LatLng(gLat,gLong);
                    var title:String = artistXML.title; 
                    var wanneer:String = artistXML.startDate;
                    var waar:String = artistXML.venue.location.city;
                    var pic:String = artistXML.venue.image.(@size=="medium");

                    var marker:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(gLat, gLong));
                    var info:InfoWindowOptions = new InfoWindowOptions();


                    marker.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:Event):void {

                        var marker:Marker = event.target as Marker;
                        marker.openInfoWindow(new InfoWindowOptions({contentHTML: "<p><b>" + title + "</b></p><br/><p>" + wanneer + "</p> <br/> <p>" + waar + "</p>"}));

                    }); 

                    map.addOverlay(marker);

                    Goverlay++;

                }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the values somewhere before you start the next loop.

I'm not sure what the structure of your `Marker` and `InfoWindowOptions` classes are, so there might be a better way, but here's a naive solution:

Create 2 arrays called `mapMarkers` and `infoWindows`. For each loop push the new Marker and the new InfoWindowOptions instances into the appropriate arrays. You'll need to set those variables on the InfoWindowOptions too. Then in your click handler you can lookup the index of the Marker that was clicked (`mapMarkers.indexOf(marker)`) and use that index to get the corresponding InfoWindowOptions.